Vba Excel 2016 - After using the AdvencedFilter function, I cannot edit cells when FormulaBar is disabled
Simple code tested on two computers. The cells are frozen in the sheet when FormulaBars is hide.
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Filtr = Range("G1").CurrentRegion
    Set Zakres = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Zakres.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, Filtr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


text
I found a solution but it's not perfect.
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
    Range("A2").Select


